# Ayuda con llenar dato gridview c# MVC

Tags: c#, mvc

resulta que tengo un problema sin resolver, tengo un proyecto de prueba el cual me muestra un campo despues de asignar un valor, asi le asingo un valor al campo que muestra en un gridview, esto esta en windows forms, al pasarlo a vista por que debe ser web, no logro la forma de hacerlo funcionar, asi quiero que quede, a ver si alguien me puede orientar, gracias

[image: RESULTA QUE ACA CUANDO COLOCO CANTIDAD DE TARJETAS 2, ME ABRE EL GRIDVIEW ABAJO]

[image: ASIGNO EL VALOR Y LO GUARDO, SERIAN 2 TARJETAS CON UN MONTO DE 20000$]
Ahora quisiera si se pudiera asignar esto a la vista y neecsito ayuda, gracias

```html
<body>
</body>
<div class="jumbotron">
    <form action="~/Home/First" />
    <form method="post">
        <div>Nombre archivo</div>
        <div><input type="text" name="txtNombreArchivo" /></div>
        <div>Cantidad tarjetas</div>
        <div><input type="text" name="txtCantidadTarjetas" /></div>
        <div>nombre Afiliado</div>
        <div><input type="text" name="txtNombreAfiliado" /></div>
        <div>BIN</div>
        <div><input type="text" name="txtBIN" /></div>
        <div>fecha vigencia</div>
        <div><input type="text" name="dtpFechaVigencia" /></div>
        <div>monto</div>
        <div><input type="text" name="txtMonto" /></div>
        <input type="submit" value="agregar" />
    </form>
</div>
```

```
        public void First(string txtNombreArchivo, string txtCantidadTarjetas, string txtNombreAfiliado, string txtBIN, DateTime dtpFechaVigencia, string txtTextoMonto, string txtMonto)
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Insertar"].ToString()))
        {
            try
            {
                BC.Funciones funciones = new Funciones();

                if (!Directory.Exists(@"Respaldo"))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(@"Respaldo");
                }

                funciones.EscribirCSV("Numero Afiliado;Cuenta;Clave;Vigencia;Nombre afiliado;Texto;Track1 Banda;Track2 Banda;EAN13;BIN", int.Parse(txtCantidadTarjetas.ToString()), txtNombreArchivo.ToString());
                Random rnd = new Random();

                int consecutivo = 1;
                int random9 = rnd.Next(100000000, 999999999);

                int rowcount = int.Parse(txtCantidadTarjetas.ToString());



                TarjetaTicket[] tarjetaTickets = new TarjetaTicket[int.Parse(txtCantidadTarjetas.ToString())];
                for (int i = 0; i <= rowcount - 1; i++)
                {
                    BC.TarjetaTicket tarjetaTicket = new TarjetaTicket();
                    int nro1 = rnd.Next(10000000, 99999999);
                    int nro2 = rnd.Next(10000000, 99999999);
                    int clave = rnd.Next(1000, 9999);
                    int quince1 = rnd.Next(10000000, 99999999);
                    int quince2 = rnd.Next(1000000, 9999999);

                    string Track1 = "B" + nro1 + nro2 + "^    /                     ^" + random9.ToString();
                    string Track2 = nro1.ToString() + nro2.ToString() + "=" + quince1 + quince2;
                    funciones.EscribirCSV(consecutivo.ToString("0000") + ";" + nro1.ToString() + nro2.ToString() + ";" + clave + ";" + dtpFechaVigencia.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd").Substring(0, 10) +
                        ";" + txtNombreAfiliado.ToString() + ";" + txtTextoMonto.ToString() + ";" + Track1 + ";" + Track2 + ";" + nro1 + nro2.ToString().Substring(0, 4) + ";" + txtBIN.ToString(), int.Parse(txtCantidadTarjetas.ToString()), txtNombreArchivo.ToString());
                    consecutivo++;

                    tarjetaTicket.NumeroTarjeta = nro1.ToString() + nro2.ToString();
                    tarjetaTicket.FechaCreacionTarjeta = DateTime.Now;
                    tarjetaTicket.FechaVigenciaTarjeta = dtpFechaVigencia.Date;
                    tarjetaTicket.MontoTarjeta = txtMonto.ToString();
                    tarjetaTicket.HashOriginal = rnd.Next(100000, 999999).ToString();

                    tarjetaTickets[i] = tarjetaTicket;
                }


            string query = "INSERT INTO [mae_ticket] ([mti_nombre_ticket], [mti_total_tarjetas], [mti_fecha_creacion], [mti_nombre_afiliado], [mti_BIN])" +
                    " VALUES (@txtNombreArchivo, @txtCantidadTarjetas ,@txtNombreAfiliado, @txtBIN, @dtpFechaVigencia)";

                BC.Ticket ticket = new Ticket();
                ticket.NombreTicket = txtNombreArchivo.ToString();
                ticket.Bin = txtBIN.ToString();
                ticket.TotalTarjetas = int.Parse(txtCantidadTarjetas.ToString());
                ticket.FechaCreacionTicket = DateTime.Now;
                ticket.NombreAfiliado = txtNombreAfiliado.ToString();
                funciones.PoblarProceso(ticket, tarjetaTickets);

            /*    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtNombreArchivo", txtNombreArchivo.ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtCantidadTarjetas", txtCantidadTarjetas.ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtNombreAfiliado", txtNombreAfiliado.ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtBIN", txtBIN.ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dtpFechaVigencia", dtpFechaVigencia.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
              //  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtMonto", txtMonto.ToString());

                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();*/
            }
            catch (Exception ron)
            {
                Exception ex;
                //MessageBox.Show(ron.Message);
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Esto es confuso. Es web o escritorio? porque lo que mostras es escritorio. Y mas alla de eso, el problema que tenes tambien es confuso.

Comment: Quieres implementar lo que tienes pero en un proyecto web?

Comment: Lo exlico bien, eso mismo quiero pasarlo pero a una vista, la vista ya la tengo hecha!, pero no se como lo haria para que el gridview se vea igual que aca

Comment: ya tienes tu funcion que retorna la informacion del controller, al view?, ahi dice MVC

Comment: Lo acabo de colocar en la demo!

Comment: sigo sin entender el problema.

Comment: No logro hacer que ese form, llene los datos de igual manera en mi vista, el form es el ejemplo de como quiero que funcione pero en la vista no me carga nada . .

Comment: pero no existe un gridview en mvc, no al menos no como control, salvo que estes usando un helper que genere una tabla, como ser el WebGrid https://www.variablenotfound.com/2011/02/webgrid-en-mvc-3-paso-paso.html  pero para eso necesitas tener un model que usar el cshtml

Comment: Gracias leandro!, otra consulta, no puedo agregar nada a mi base de datos, viendolo de ese modo, se podria verificar el pro que ?